# Conda install pydup failure

Tags: conda, pydub

I have just started on Python. I am not able to install PYDUP in Conda. It gives PackagesNotFounderror for pydup. it lists current channels - win-64 and noarch in conda-forge.I am on conda 4.9.1

Comment: It might not be distributed on conda. The docs seem to recommend installation with `pip`: https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub#installation

Comment: FYI, on installing non-Conda packages: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#installing-non-conda-packages  Also, note the "Using Pip in a Conda Environment" part of the documentation, which generally recommends against using `pip` in the **base** environment.